# $router.replace() doesn't update browser query string

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

The problem is that the query string does not show up in the browser's URL bar.

The code updates the query string in order to keep track of a product configuration.

There are two methods - the first one chooses the model and the second one sets options for that model. Here's the code (the values for the query string are placeholders now):

Methods:

```
chooseModel (option) {
  this.$router.replace({
    path: this.$route.path,
    query: {m: 'model'},
  })
},
choose (option) {
  if (!this.selectedModel) return
  let opt = {}
  opt[option] = option
  this.$router.push({          // I've tried push and replace
    path: this.$route.path,
    query: Object.assign(this.$route.query, opt),
  })
},
```

Computed:

```
selectedModel () {
  return this.$route.query.m
},
```

When `chooseModel` is invoked the query string that the browser displays shows up as it should: `http://localhost:8080/custom/?m=model`. But when `choose` is invoked the query string that the browser displays remains the same.

FWIW, I have changed the code in `chooseModel` to set multiple query string values and they all show up. Apparently it is trying to modify that value that causes problems.

Using the debugger I can see that `$route.query` is correct - it reflects the changes I've made to the query.

I seen the same behavior with both Firefox and Chrome, so it apparently isn't browser-specific.

What do I need to do to get the browser to display the updated query string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is my bug but strange behavior nonetheless.

[Because a route is immutable](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object) `Object.assign()` is not able to modify it. What is odd is that after my attempt to modify the query string the new route object showed the values I was attempting to set even though the browser didn't display them.

The fix is simple - don't try to modify the route object:

`query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, opt)`

(thanks VCavallo for new link location)

Comment: Great answer @bmacnaughton, and completely unexpected.

Comment: They seem to have moved that link to here: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object